Как задать зависимость вывода вопроса от количества предыдущих правильных ответов на python?
Есть викторина с вопросами и ответами.
Вопросы выходят в случайном порядке из списка.
В цикле показывается несколько вариантов ответов в том числе и правильный ответ.
Если с первого раза выбрать правильный ответ на вопрос, то прибавляется один балл на этот вопрос.
Иначе если с первого раза выбран неправильный ответ то баллы обнуляются и прибавляется одна ошибка за каждый неправильный ответ, балл не прибавляется когда выбран правильный ответ в этом случае.
В итоге каждый вопрос должен набрать количество баллов указанное в программе. Например 3 балла. Это значит на этот вопрос было дано З правильных ответа подряд.
Вопрос заключается в том, как сделать зависимость вывода конкретного вопроса от его количества баллов.
Например если у вопроса 1 правильный ответ т.е 1 балл, то этот вопрос должен появиться после 1 мин. Если у вопроса 2 балла то этот вопрос должен появиться после 2 мин.
Или сделать зависимость следующего вывода вопроса с помощью количества циклов. Например если у вопроса 1 правильный ответ т.е. 1 балл, то этот вопрос должен появиться после 10 циклов вывода других вопросов. Если у вопроса 2 балла то этот вопрос должен появиться после 20 выводов других вопросов и т.д.

Ну добавьте в класс "Вопрос" поле вроде next_run и пишите туда желаемое время следующего вывода или желаемый счётчик вывода. Счётчик заданных вопросов можете вести отдельной переменной просто. Время не нужно отдельно вести, просто берёте текущее и проверяете.
